# onRequestPermissionsResult is not being called

Tags: android

I want to ask for permission for Write External Storage for `Marshmallow`. I can't see any option to override `onRequestPermissionsResult`. I am able to call `requestPermissions`. I have created below method. Now, I want to call new action based on result. Please help me to go ahead.

```
public static boolean verifyPermissions(Activity activity,
            String[] grantResults) {
        boolean allPermissionsGranted = true;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            for (String result : grantResults) {
                int outresult = activity.checkSelfPermission(result);
                if (outresult != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    allPermissionsGranted = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!allPermissionsGranted) {
                activity.requestPermissions(grantResults, 1);
            }
        }

        return allPermissionsGranted;
    }
```

I have `Fragment`. I tried below code directly but it is showing error 'The method onRequestPermissionsResult(int, String[], int[]) of type Products must override or implement a supertype method'.
**Code :**

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
            @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    }
```

Comment: [Override it in your Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback.html)

Comment: @MuratK., I can't see any that option in `override/implement` methods. Please check updated post.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't see any option to override onRequestPermissionsResult.

You would override it on the `Activity` that you are passing into this method.

Comment: But I can't see any that option in `override/implement` methods. Please check updated post.

Comment: @JeetenParmar: "I have Fragment" -- that is irrelevant. You are calling `requestPermissions()` on an `Activity`. You need to implement `onRequestPermissionsResult()` **on the same `Activity`**. If you switch to calling `requestPermissions()` on the `Fragment`, *then* you can override `onRequestPermissionsResult()` on that same `Fragment`, so long as you are using the fragments backport (`android.support.v4.app.Fragment`) and have a new enough support library (23.0.0 or newer).

Comment: I am calling `requestPermissions()` from fragment only.

Comment: Let me add latest support library and check it.